# How do stdin, stdout, stderr get closed?

Tags: c

When you exit the program, how do these `FILE*` objects get closed and released?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From C99 §7.20.4.3/3:

> Next, all open streams with unwritten buffered data are ﬂushed, **all
>   open streams are closed**, and all ﬁles created by the tmpfile function
>   are removed.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html) (aligned with C99) spells it out better:

> The exit() function shall then flush all open streams with unwritten
>   buffered data and close all open streams.

Comment: Does that mean it closes any other streams the user might have opened as well? How does it know about them?

Comment: @Paul It knows because `stdio` does its own bookkeeping. `fopen` does more than returning you the `FILE *`.

Answer (score 6):

They are closed by the C runtime code which is automatically linked to your program - the code that calls your main() function also calls exit() after main() returns.